# PHP: Подмена объекта в конструкторе

Tags: php

Бьюсь над вопросом, как получить имя экземпляра класса внутри метода объекта этого класса. С внешней стороны все проходит благополучно, но внутри функция определения имени переменной не срабатывает. Отсюда и появился вопрос можно ли в конструкторе переопределить порожденный объект? И еще вопрос использование eval() - это плохой тон?<br> 
<b>UPD:</b><br>
Удивительно, но часть ответа на этот вопрос - подсказали в другом топике: <a href="http://hashcode.ru/questions/54755/">Вызов функции цепочкой после конструктора</a> <br>
В принципе задача почти решена, за одним исключением, для полного удобства нехватает следующего как вызвать деструктор сразу после срабатывания конструктора или вызвать функцию цепочкой после конструктора(с обычным методом класса проблем не возникает)?

Comment: Помоему вы не в ту сторону едете, раз задаете такие вопросы

Answer (score 1):

Точно не понял ваш вопрос, но, возможно вы ищите "магическую" константу `__CLASS__`?

Так-же в php 5.3+ есть функция `get_called_class` которая внутри любого класса и любого метода может определить имя класса которые его вызвал.

PS: уж точно не стоит писать такого ужаса как `get_class($this)`

Comment: get_class($this) - этот ужас написан в примере функции на офф сайте http://md.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php, причем не в разделе комментов пользователей, а в оффициальном примере использования, так что способ имеет место быть

Comment: зачем такое делать если есть `__CLASS__`?<br>
В офф примере такое написано для лучшего понимания функции(чтобы не усложнять), не более. Печально что вы этого не понимаете...

Answer (score 0):

get_class($this) вернет название класса внутри класса,
get_class($obj) вернет имя класса переданного объекта во внешнем коде.
т.е. в конструкторе

```
public function __consruct(){
    $this->_className = get_class($this);
}
```

передаст переменной $this->_className имя класса. По той же схеме get_parent_class() - работает с именем родительского класса.

IMHO лучше разобраться с правильными функциями чем костыли лепить

Comment: Это вы сами придумали ? 
Вообщемто конструктор ничего не возвращает. И ваш пример не будет работать, а по поводу get_class - это верно

Comment: ups, согласен, с конструктором херню сморозил, думал сначала пример использования внутри одного класса экземпляра другого класса написать да чет заумничался и ерунду написал.

Comment: @zippp можно ведь исправить

Comment: убрал из коммента бредовый участок

Comment: Мне нужно было имя экземпляра класса, а не сам класс.